# Segmentation fault in dlib c++ probability assignment

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, dlib, bayesian-networks

I am using dlib in c++. I am stuck in the following code. 'bn' is a 'directed_graph' and parent_state is a 'assignment' type. This code worked for all other input data but it failed here somehow. The cout statement are included to show that it fulfills the conditions as given in document as referred in the comment.

```
  parent_state.clear();
  parent_state.add(12,1);
  parent_state.add(15,0);
  cout << bn.number_of_nodes() << endl;
  cout <<bn.node(11).number_of_parents() << endl;
  cout << bn.has_edge(12,11) << " " << bn.has_edge(15,11) << endl;
  cout << node_num_values(bn,12) << " " <<parent_state[12] << " " << num_values(bn,15) << " " << parent_state[15] << " " << endl;
  set_node_probability(bn,11,0,parent_state,0);
```

The last line shows the error where the code stops. It stops with a segmentation fault.

```
  24
  2
  1 1
  2 1 2 0
  Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: This question needs more information. What have you tried? What are bn and parent_state? Did you make sure your arguments meet all the requirements as set out [in the docs](ftp://ftp.nist.gov/pub/mel/michalos/Software/Optimization/dlib-18.9/docs/dlib/bayes_utils/bayes_utils_abstract.h.html#set_node_probability)?

Comment: @Xiao Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile and run your program with DEBUG #defined then it should tell you where the error is when you run it.